# jQuery selectpicker - How to select empty option?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using jquery selectpicker

After user select on of the option i would like to allow him to clear his select and submit empty value, so i add empty option -

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="catID" data-live-search="true">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="6"> attrac cat 1</option>
    <option value="3"> attrac cat 2</option>
    <option value="26">attrac cat 4</option>
</select>
```

but the script not allow him to select this option...

Answer (score 0):

please try this code

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="catID" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="6"> attrac cat 1</option>
    <option value="3"> attrac cat 2</option>
    <option value="26">attrac cat 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I have an option that says "Choose {{item}}". I give it a disabled class that makes it a bit faded and give it no value. It makes the select look a bit better and helps with this problem.

Example:

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="catID" data-live-search="true">
  <option class="disabled" value="">Choose option...</option>
  <option value="6"> attrac cat 1</option>
  <option value="3"> attrac cat 2</option>
  <option value="26">attrac cat 4</option>
</select>
```

Edit:

If you are using bootstrap the disabled class is already available

The class could look something like:

```
.disabled {
  color: light-grey;
}
```